# PHP Code spinner

Tags: javascript, spinner, loading

I have a page with a PHP code that loads html code from other pages and it takes quite awhile before the user can see the page fully loaded, I was wondering how can I add like a spinner image while the PHP code is beeing processed.

I've tried this (adding 1 loader div and 1 content div)

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    function preloader(){
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
    }//preloader
    window.onload = preloader;
// ]]></script>
```

But that wont work, I need the spinner to be displayed while the PHP code is working but theres no output.

Comment: can you show more code please

Comment: Well the PHP code is just some cURL stuff so it takes a while to my page to output text.

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of work you have to think to use AJAX calls, in that way you can load a big chunk of data showing a spinner as you want.

An example to load content via Ajax with jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  // OPEN SPINNER
  $.ajax({url:"url.php",success:function(result){
    // CLOSE SPINNER AND HANDLE DATA
  }});
});
```

You can find lot of information about how to work with Ajax on Internet.